# Why are my traces in eagle highlighted after I moved a component?

Tags: eaglecad, routing

Good day, I am currently working on a PCB in Autodesk Eagle and was almost done routing when I had to move a component and now I have all these traces that are highlighted with lines and I don't know what it means or how to fix it. It seems like it is telling you there has been a change of some sort. Is there a way to accept the change so that all of these highlighted traces are fixed at the same time? Thanks!

[image: Highlighted traces with lines]

Comment: Have you ran a DRC check? Those don't seem to be wrong though..

Comment: They are DRC errors. If you run the DRC again they will either go away, or you will be shown a list of errors telling you what they are. Include a screenshot of those errors if you need help deciphering them.

Comment: Awesome thank you Tom and Wesley, that solved my problem. I just ran the DRC and most of them went away and the ones that stayed I fixed. Thanks!